# Is there a liquid filter to limit a url to the domain name only?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm wondering if there is a liquid filter that would limit a url to the domain name only.

For example, let's say I wanted to have a link to an article called "The Greatest Article Ever" and the url was something unwieldily like http://example.com/long/ugly/directory/123948/name. Let's also say I had both of these values in my YAML metadata in an array as "title:" and "url:" respectively, and my desired output was something like this:

```
<div class="cool-articles">
  <a href="http://example.com/long/ugly/directory/123948/name">
    The Greatest Article Ever
  </a>
  <span>example.com</span>
</div>
```

How might I use liquid to limit the array-item.url to the domain name only?

I've been searching through the liquid docs for a nice filter to do it, but I've only found remove (which can nix the "http://") but nothing to just strip out everything but the domain name.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can try to split the URL on slashes (after removing "http://") and get the first element of the resulting array. For example:

```
{{ url | remove:'http://' | split:'/' | first }}
```

I didn't test it, but it should work reasonably well for the most part. With this pipeline in place, you just need to construct the output as you said:

```
<div class="cool-articles">
  <a href="{{ url }}">
    {{ title }}
  </a>
  <span>{{ url | remove:'http://' | split:'/' | first }}</span>
</div>
```

I hope that helps. :)

Comment: This gave me the hint i needed to lookup `replace` instead of `remove`. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following, which works irrespective of the network protocol like **http** or **https**:

```
<span>{{ url | split: "//" | last | split: "/" | first }}</span>
```